# Environment variables in Postgres C extension

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, environment-variables, c

I cannot get environment variable in my PostgreSQL C extension code.

For example, this function always returns `111`:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(myinc);
Datum
myinc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  int32 arg = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
  char* envar = getenv("MYINC");
  if (envar) {
    PG_RETURN_INT32(arg + atoi(envar));
  } else {
    PG_RETURN_INT32(111);
  }
}
```

While this C program works as expected, it prints whatever `MYINC` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  printf("MYINC: %s", getenv("MYINC"));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work just fine. Note, however, that it will take the variable from the environment of the PostgreSQL server process, not your current client process.

Comment: How do I save variable to the environment of the PostgreSQL server process? I've tried adding it to `/etc/environment` and also to `~/.profile` (with restart of PostgreSQL service and even with PC restart) but it didn't work. I'm using Ubuntu via WSL2.

Comment: As far as I remember, the Ubuntu PostgreSQL binaries have a special environment file under `/etc/postgresql`.

Comment: It works. Thank you Albe!